# gTTSで作製したMP3の音声を、一時保存せず直接再生するには？

Tags: python, mp3

```
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO

mp3_fp = BytesIO()
tts = gTTS('hello', 'en')
tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
```

gTTSでmp3ファイルを作成するのはいいんですけれども、
いちいちセーブをして、そのセーブによってできたmp3ファイルを
再生するという手順をとっています。
　こういう回りくどいことをしないで、直接音を鳴らせないものかと
思いました。
　そこで、公式を見てみると、
http://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#languages-gtts-lang

> Playing sound directly
>   There’s quite a few libraries that do this. Write ‘hello’ to a file-like object do further manipulation::

と書いてあり、直接音を再生する手順が書いてあるように読めるのですが、
上のサンプルコードからどのようにすれば、直接音が出るようになるのでしょうか。

その下に、

> Load `audio_fp` as an mp3 file in
>     the audio library of your choice

と書いてあり、あなた自身の選択でオーディオライブラリ内のmp3ファイルとしてaudio_fpをロードしなさいと書いてあります。こうしろということなのでしょうが、いまいちわからなかったです。
    python3.6.3 gTTS2.0

Comment: gTTSはあくまでテキストを音声に変換するライブラリで,音声を再生する機能は持っていないように見えます.音声を再生するのは別のライブラリでしょう.ファイルの場合はどのように再生していますか?再生はOSやオーディオスタック依存の機能のため,何を使って再生しているかわからないとファイルライクオブジェクトに音声を保存しても何に渡せばよいのかわかりません.

Comment: @ncaq os.startfile()で、指定のディレクトリのmp3ファイルを打ち出すようにしております。MediaPlayerだったり、ITunesだったり、画面が出てきます。やはり変換のみのライブラリですか。画像と音声をスタイリッシュにウィジェットと連携させたいと思っているんですが、別物扱いになる感じがしていやです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://teratail.com/questions/118339

teratailという別の質問サイトで似たような質問を見付けました。

それに対しての解答があったのですが、`io.BytesIO`と、`pygame.mixer`を

を組み合わせて音を再生することが、できなくはないようです。

しかし、不安定になるため、一旦セーブした方がいいとのことでした。

`wav`を再生するモジュールは、結構ありますが、`mp3`を再生するモジュールは、
恐らく`pygame`くらいしかないし、自分も過去`mp3`を直接再生しようとして、
`pygame`を使用したところ、クラッシュの連続だったので、こうした機能の
将来の発展を待ち望むことにして、とりあえずは据え置きということにしようと思います。

ありがとうございました。